# Trouble publishing rpm artifact to yum snapshot repo using Gradle

Tags: gradle, rpm, yum

I've been trying to publish a rpm file (built using Gradle-custom plugin) to a yum snapshot repo using Gradle (nexus-yum plugin installed on repo). However, the upload fails and I get an error 400. I further understand that this is because my build script is attempting to upload my rpm artifact to a release repo instead of the snapshot repo. It would be great if anyone could share thoughts as to where I could be going wrong ?

Comment: Is the RPM artifact a release or a SNAPSHOT?

Answer (score 0):

Are you specifying the snapshots area of your repo?

The answer to : [using gradle to deploy features.xml to nexus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13631260/using-gradle-to-deploy-features-xml-to-nexus/13647231#13647231) explains how to update your maven settings.xml to exclude locations from a public repo and upload archives to releases area (same applies for snapshot)

Of course if you are publishing to a snapshot dir you must have a -SNAPSHOT extension.